PKCE verification failed when login to keycloak with multiple tabs
The above error occurs when I try to log in to a Datahub application that has Keycloak authentication integrated. These are the steps to reproduce the error:

Open the first tab and access the Datahub application (localhost:9002), the browser will redirect to the keycloak login page (localhost:8022/realms/datahub-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth...)
Open the second tab, continue accessing the Datahub application, the browser will still redirect to the Keycloak login page
And now go back to the first tab, enter information and log in, and the error appears from now

Instead of taking me to the Datahub dashboard, the browser redirected me to a login error page with the following error: Failed to sign in using Single Sign-On provider. Please try again, or contact your DataHub Administrator.
When I look at the Datahub log I see the following:
DEBUG o.p.o.c.a.OidcAuthenticator - Token response: status=400, content={"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"PKCE verification failed"}
and the error:
ERROR controllers.SsoCallbackController - Caught exception while attempting to handle SSO callback! It's likely that SSO integration is mis-configured.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1770)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.$anonfun$execute$1(HttpExecutionContext.scala:64)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant
at auth.sso.oidc.custom.CustomOidcAuthenticator.validate(CustomOidcAuthenticator.java:193)
at auth.sso.oidc.custom.CustomOidcAuthenticator.validate(CustomOidcAuthenticator.java:44)
at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.lambda$retrieveCredentials$0(BaseClient.java:70)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.retrieveCredentials(BaseClient.java:67)
at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getCredentials(IndirectClient.java:143)
at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultCallbackLogic.perform(DefaultCallbackLogic.java:85)
at auth.sso.oidc.OidcCallbackLogic.perform(OidcCallbackLogic.java:118)
at controllers.SsoCallbackController$SsoCallbackLogic.perform(SsoCallbackController.java:119)
at controllers.SsoCallbackController$SsoCallbackLogic.perform(SsoCallbackController.java:93)
at org.pac4j.play.CallbackController.lambda$callback$0(CallbackController.java:54)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
... 8 common frames omitted
I hope the community can explain why I get the error in the above case. How to solve this problem every time I log in on the first tab.
